# Error when converting AG Grid to enterprise

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am currently trying to convert a project I have that is using AG Grid free to enterprise free trial.  However, when following the instructions on the AG Grid site I am getting this error:

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EnterpriseCoreModule' of undefined***

Thinking it might probably be due to the project I created I tried building on a new one but I am still getting the same error.

Has anyone encountered this error?  Looked on the net and could didn't find any results.  Can anyone help in activating my AG Grid to enterprise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine. 
let's proceed installation step by step

1. install all dependencies

```
npm i --save ag-grid-angular
npm i --save ag-grid-community
npm i --save ag-grid-enterprise
```

2. import deps in `app.module.ts`

```
import {AgGridModule} from "ag-grid-angular";
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AgGridModule.withComponents([])]
})
```

3. import  ag-Grid styles - in `styles.scss`

```
@import "~@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

4.setting the license key in `main.ts`

but the order of the modules is IMPORTANT!

> We recommend setting the license key in your main boot files (typically named either main.ts or boot.ts, before you bootstrap your application.

```
import { LicenseManager } from "ag-grid-enterprise";


LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("YOUR_KEY");
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help.  As I mentioned I already have an existing and working grid in a project.  So I only need to install ag-grid-enterprise correct?  And  just import the license manager?  Also I have tried recreating it on a new project but still getting the same error.  I am not sure if it has something to do with my Angular or something.  Will try to do it again following your steps.

Comment: yes for enterprise we just need: 1) install ag-grid-enterprise 2)And just import the license manager. That's all, it should be easy to install, it takes of 2minutes to install for me. Maybe there is an issue with the new version of ag-grid. I use next versions: `    "ag-grid-angular": "^21.2.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^21.2.2",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^21.2.2",`

Comment: Unfortunately the error is still there.

ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:493 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EnterpriseCoreModule' of undefined
    at Object.../../node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:493)

Comment: I have the following versions:
"ag-grid-angular": "^21.2.2",
"ag-grid-community": "^21.2.2",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^22.0.0",
Will try the 21.2.2 version of enterprise

Thanks

Comment: maybe problem is in a new version of ag-grid-enterprise, try my version

Comment: Yup its the version.  Tried 21.2.2 it is now working.  Thank you for the help