# Using ag-grid-commiunity, ag-grid-enterprise create tables

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I installed the ag-grid enterprise (i have the license also). But the table doesn't come with proper styles. it also changed the other tables(without created the enterprise) styles also. I tried it in different versions of ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-community, ag-grid-enterprise. but I got the same issue.

I tried the latest version(22.0.0) of these modules.
 "ag-grid": "^18.1.3",
 "ag-grid-angular": "^22.0.0",
 "ag-grid-community": "^22.0.0",
 "ag-grid-enterprise": "^22.0.0", Then then the project didn't load and nothing was shown in the browser.
I tried it in different versions of ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-community, ag-grid-enterprise. Then the project loaded. But didn't get the proper styles.
Why this happens and what versions should I uses to get the right versions?.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UpqG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use next versions

```
   "ag-grid-angular": "^21.2.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^21.2.2",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^21.2.2",
```

Here you can find step-by-step instructions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59197319/9200941

> dont forget import ag-Grid styles - in styles.scss
>
> and add class to grid

```
<ag-grid-angular
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
```

in my project I use next import in `styles.scss`

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

I recommend not use `"ag-grid-enterprise": "^21.2.2"` for now, it has some issue with `EnterpriseCoreModule`, use follow that i write above - it is stable versions

Comment: I suppose you just did not add class to grid `class="ag-theme-balham"`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world - here simple repo , maybe you just missed something

Comment: here documentation https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/ try to install new project step by step